# overflow issue in divided page into two equal parts bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

he guys i have a annoying issue i need your help i have a picture which size is:

```
W:814px
H:685
```

should be placed on the left side of the page ,I have a table which should be placed on the right side of the page,I thought I can achieve it with a simple bootstrap below:

```
        <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <table>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

but it becomes like the screen shot i have added here [image: issue]

i dont wana change the size of the pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here everything looks better with bootstrap latest version! Could you inspect your page

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/640/425" class="img-fluid"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you used img-fluid but it does not affect the actual size of the pic?

Comment: From Inspect class `img-fluid`  affect the image!